# Type-safe criteria query, new feature of JPA 2.0: Path unknown?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jakarta-ee

When starting a new Java EE (maven) web app in jbdevstudio there is already some code included, inclusive a Member model with Registration.
In the MemberRepository class there two methods which use criteria queries this way:

```
public Member findByEmail(String email) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Member> criteria = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
    Root<Member> member = criteria.from(Member.class);
    // Swap criteria statements if you would like to try out type-safe criteria queries, a new
    // feature in JPA 2.0
    // criteria.select(member).where(cb.equal(member.get(Member_.name), email));
    criteria.select(member).where(cb.equal(member.get("email"), email));
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
}

public List<Member> findAllOrderedByName() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Member> criteria = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
    Root<Member> member = criteria.from(Member.class);
    // Swap criteria statements if you would like to try out type-safe criteria queries, a new
    // feature in JPA 2.0
    // criteria.select(member).orderBy(cb.asc(member.get(Member_.name)));
    criteria.select(member).orderBy(cb.asc(member.get("name")));
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

I would like to use (e.g. try out) the codeline(s) of the suggested type-safe criteria queries, but the compiler has a problem with `Member_`.
What am I missing here?

Greetings
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use [JPA Static Metamodel](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html#metamodel) classes in Criteria queries you have to first CREATE the static metamodel classes. All JPA providers include a way of doing it, and their documentation would tell you how that is done. The link here shows it for one

Comment: Thanks much for your fast and helpful answer. That worked fine. Additional question: Ive put for now the Member_ class as a inner class of the MemberRepository class (And made class static). Does that make sense, or is it better to put it in an own file (maybe its later needed elsewhere again(?).

Comment: Your JPA provider will generate the classes for you (normally via an annotation processor), so it will decide where they are put. My provider (DataNucleus) puts them in the same package as the entity class.